# How to pass a validation group to a custom constraint

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, annotations

I created some constraints for validating in Spring MVC but I'm having problems defining validation groups for the constraints

Here is an example of one of the constraints I created

**The Constraint**

```
public @interface DropDown {

    String value();
    String message() default"{DropDown}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default{};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
}
```

This is the validator class I created to go with the constraint.

**The validator**

```
public class DropdownConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DropDown, String>{

    private String annotationSelect;

    @Override
    public void initialize(DropDown dropdown) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.annotationSelect = dropdown.value();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String selectField, ConstraintValidatorContext cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(selectField == null){

          return false;
        }

        if(selectField.equals(annotationSelect)){

            return false;
        }
        else

            return true;


    }



}
```

In one of my models this is how I'm using the constraint

```
public Modelname{
@DropDown("Please Select")
private String selection;
//getters --Setters
}
```

The constraint checks if the selected value in a drop down box has changed. If the value is still "Please Select" then validation errors are triggered. This works well but for my form I want to skip some boxes based on conditions on the screen.

Just like standard JSR 303 validations. I want to use my constraint like this

```
public Modelname{
@DropDown("Please Select", groups={displayed.class})
private String selection;
}
```

I assumed since I define values passed to the validator, groups should be defined the same way but I have spent all day searching online and I can't seem to find any documentation that clearly explains how to do it. Even on this site

This is how I'm using the constraint in one of the models.

```
 public class Personalinfo {

        private int id;


        @DropDown("Please Select", groups ={displayedgroups.class})
        private String title;

        @NotBlank(message = "Please provide your name", groups ={displayedgroups.class})
        private String name;

//rest of the class attributes with getters and setters
}
```

On the following line is where I get compilation error: Invalid MemberValuePairs

`@DropDown("Please Select", groups ={displayedgroups.class})`

Thanks

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/

Comment: Define "doesn't work", precisely. Include any error message you get, expected vs. actual behavior.

Comment: I get a compilation error. "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: Post your **real** code, the complete and exact error message you get, and tell us which line of the code this message refers to.

Comment: Besides the Model classes I posted the code in the question is my exact code. I'll update the question with the real Model.

Comment: `publib Modelname{` can't be your exact code. And the most important part is missing: the complete and exact error message you get, and  which line of the code this message refers to.

Comment: That was a spelling mistake thanks. I updated the question with a sample of  my code and the error I get.

Comment: Your question saved me from all this non-really-validation-annotation-acpect stuff. Could be said the solution is out-of-the-box, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is the same as the one used in your NotBlank example:

```
@DropDown(message = "Please Select", groups = {displayedgroups.class})
```

or

```
@DropDown(value = "Please Select", groups = {displayedgroups.class})
```

Depending on which attribute (value or message) you want to populate with "Please Select".

You can only omit the attribute name if

- the attribute is `value`, and
- it's the only attribute you want to set in the annotation.

Comment: Yes that is correct syntax but that was not my problem. "Please Select" in this case is a value I use to check if the person selected something on the the dropbox or not. Sometimes when validating in spring you can use groups to validate based on certain conditions. Now this works well for default annotations like @NotBlank. But I can't seem to find a way to define my custom annotations such that they accept the parameter "groups = {class}". I had to use another means cause I have a tight deadline but it would be good to know how to do it.

Comment: So, when you type `@DropDown(value = "Please Select", groups = {displayedgroups.class})`, what is exact and complete compiler error message?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. I had to remove the "**default{};**" next to "`Class<?>[] groups();`"

```
  public @interface DropDown {

    String value();
    String message() default"{DropDown}";

    Class<?>[] groups();
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
}
```

Now on the model the annotation will expect that you define the attribute **groups**. For example.

```
public Modelname{

  @DropDown("Please Select", groups=displayed.class)
  private String selection;
  //rest of the code here

}
```